# Fstab failing but mount works

Tags: raspbian, mount, fstab

Currently trying to get my external USB drive to mount via `fstab`. However it causes the system to go into emergency mode on reboot.

If I comment out the fstab line, it works fine. Then I mount the drive using this command:

`sudo mount -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,umask=003,blksize=4096 /dev/sda2 /mnt/library`

This works great and gets it right first time. Here is my fstab line:

`/dev/sda2   /mnt/library  vfat  rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,umask=003,blksize=4096   0   0`

I thought it would be a filesystem error, however `df -T` reports that the mounted drive is using vfat:

`/dev/sda2      vfat     976188320 382612672 593575648  40% /mnt/library`

Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck w/this? I'm having a similar problem that appeared to work fine with Wheezy, but not with Jessie. /dev/sda1 /usb vfat defaults,noatime,no fail,user,rw 0 3